# Como converte um tipo enum em list?

Tags: c#, .net, lista, conversão-de-tipo, enums

Existe alguma forma de converte um `Enum` em `List`?

```
public enum TiposHospedagem
{
    Casa = 1,
    Hotel = 2,
    Pousada = 3,
    CasaCampo = 4
}
```

Estou tentando vare o `enum` e adicionar na lista, mas o `foreach` não aceita fazer isso.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lista = new List<Int32>();

    foreach (var th in TiposHospedagem)
    {
        lista.Add(Convert.ToInt32(th));
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1167367/5524514

Comment: diegofm, sei que a sua intenção é ajudar, mas postei como resposta uma tradução livre da resposta no SO em inglês, pois muitos não compreendem o idioma e por este motivo utilizam o SO em Português.

Comment: @BrunoBermann não que eu me importe com isso, mas dar os créditos não seria nada ruim :)

Comment: Eu coloquei um link para o post original, será que ficaria melhor se eu colocasse mais alguma informação? Minha intenção é colaborar o máximo possível.

Comment: @diegofm, valeu pelo link, só não tinha entendido como convertia para int.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conforme [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1167367/221800), pode fazer isso:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new List<int>();
        foreach (int item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TiposHospedagem))) lista.Add(item);
        foreach (var item in lista) WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public enum TiposHospedagem {
    Casa = 1,
    Hotel = 2,
    Pousada = 3,
    CasaCampo = 4
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MF0my5). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ryS4Tg). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/List.cs).

A solução obviamente poderá variar conforme a necessidade. Então outra possibilidade seria:

```
var lista = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TiposHospedagem)).Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pkjwWl). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SJ2EqC). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/List2.cs).

Pode não ser muito performático já que usa reflexão, mas deve atender bem a maioria das necessidades.

Esse código pega todos os valores existentes na enumeração, faz um *cast* em cada um dos membros para um inteiro, já que é o tipo que se deseja (se quisesse outro poderia ser um problema) e converte para a lista. Tudo isso usando LINQ, por isso dá para fazer em uma só linha.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo aqui....

Comment: Por que não utilizar apenas `foreach (int item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TiposHospedagem)))`?

Comment: @ramaral porque o resultado de cada item retornado por [`GetValues()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx) será um `object` e se deseja um `int`. Sabe-se que o resultado será um `int`, mas precisa dizer isso pro compilador. API ruim.

Comment: Não, ele compila.

Comment: @ramaral ah, é que aí há um *cast* implícito, poderia ser feito assim também. Modifiquei, fica melhor. Créditos para você nessa parte.

Comment: Mas você tem razão: é preciso dizer isso pro compilador, usando `int item` em vez de `var item`

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte sintaxe:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(MeuEnumerador)).Cast<MeuEnumerador>();
```

E isso retornará uma interface IEnumerable especializada ao tipo MeuEnumerador.

Para converter os dados através desta interface para uma lista você deve utilizar o método ".ToList()" dela

**Observação:** É necessário incluir o namespace System.Linq no seu código para utilizar este código.

**Créditos:** Resposta baseada na pergunta do SO-En localizada neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167361/how-do-i-convert-an-enum-to-a-list-in-c)